# Linear transformations which are not invertible in a vector space V of real valued sequences

Tags: abstract-algebra

Find a vector space $V$ and maps $F,G\in L(V,V)$ such that $F\cdot G=I$ but neither $F$ nor $G$ are invertible maps.

I tried to use the vector space of all real valued sequences as V. I need to find two linear transformations as above. I got one transformation, $G:V\rightarrow V$ such that $G(a_1,a_2,...)=(a_2,a_3,...)$. But I do not know how to get $F$ such that $F\cdot  G=I$. Please help.

Comment: First, show as a lemma that if $FG = I$ then $F$ is surjective and $G$ is injective. That means your $G$ won't work. But it will work if you make that operation $F$ instead!

Comment: You have the right idea! The issue is that you can't possibly reconstruct $(a_1, a_2, \dots)$ from $(a_2, a_3, \dots)$, so no such $F$ can exist. But this function can be used as $F$ if you make an appropriate function $G$ (there is actually a unique choice for $G$ in this case)

Comment: What would that unique choice for G be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $\Bbb F$ is any field and $V$ is the space of sequences of elements of $F$, that is, of functions

$f: \Bbb N \to \Bbb F; \tag 1$

it is clear we may represent any such $f$ in the form

$f \equiv (f_1, f_2, f_3, \ldots), \; f_i \in \Bbb F, \; \forall i \in N; \tag 2$

it is easy to see that $V$ is a vector space over $\Bbb F$, with addition and scalar multiplication defined component-wise.

The function

$G:V \to V \tag 3$

given by

$G(a_1, a_2, a_3, \ldots) = (a_2, a_3, a_4, \ldots), \tag 4$

is easily seen to be $\Bbb F$-linear; it is sometimes known as the *left shift* operator on $V$.

It is easy to see that $G$ has no left inverse, that is, that there exists no

$F \in L(V, V) \tag 5$

with

$F \circ G = I; \tag 6$

for consider two sequences

$(a_1, a_2, a_3, \ldots), \; (a_1', a_2, a_3, \ldots), \; a_1' \ne a_1, \tag 7$

which differ only in the first position; if there existed $F$ as in (6), then

$(a_1, a_2, a_3, \ldots) = I(a_1, a_2, a_3, \ldots)$
$= F \circ G(a_1, a_2, a_3, \ldots) = F(a_2, a_3, a_4, \ldots), \tag 8$

and also

$(a_1', a_2, a_3, \ldots) = I(a_1', a_2, a_3, \ldots)$
$= F \circ G(a_1, a_2, a_3, \ldots) = F(a_2, a_3, a_4, \ldots); \tag 9$

together (8) and (9) yield

$(a_1, a_2, a_3, \ldots) = F(a_2, a_3, a_4, \ldots) = 
(a_1', a_2, a_3, \ldots) \Longrightarrow a_1 = a_1';  \tag{10}$

since $a_1$, $a_1'$ may be selected independently of one another, (10) is in fact a contradiction; hence there is no such $F$.

On the other hand, if we set

$G(a_1, a_2, a_3, \ldots) = (0, a_1, a_2, a_3, \ldots), \tag{11}$

and

$F(a_1, a_2, a_3, \ldots) = (a_2, a_3, a_4, \ldots), \tag{12}$

so that now $F$ is the left shift, then

$F \circ G(a_1, a_2, a_3, \ldots) = F(0, a_1, a_2, a_3, \ldots)$
$= (a_1, a_2, a_3, \ldots) = I(a_1, a_2, a_3, \ldots), \tag{13}$

showing that

$F \circ G = I; \tag{14}$

note that $F$ is not *injective*, since

$F(a_1, a_2, a_3, \ldots) = F(a_1', a_2, a_3, \ldots) \tag{15}$

even when

$a_1 \ne a_1', \tag{16}$

and $G$ is not *surjective*, since according to (11) no sequence whose first entry is non-zero is in $\text{Range}(G)$; so neither $F$ nor $G$ is invertible; we thus see that such operator pairs $F$, $G$ satisfying (14) do indeed exist.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @DD90:  you are more than welcome, my friend.  If you really found my answer helpful, you might consider upvoting/accepting it.  Cheers!